# Dynamics CRM - Get Entitiy Query results as Datasource for Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to get entity query results as a datasource and use it in a repeater.

Inside the repeater i use <%#Eval("hs_firstname")%> but i get an error when i run my solution.

My code is:

```
query = newQueryExpression("hs_personel") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("hs_firstname", "hs_surname", "hs_positionid", "hs_birthdate") };     

query.Criteria.AddCondition("statuscode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1);

result = Portal.Value.Connection.Value.Service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

Repeater1.DataSource = result.Entities;

Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Error is (i tried to translate, my framework is in my own language):

`{"DataBinding: 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity', there is no property named hs_firstname."}`

Comment: Check the attribute "hs_firstname" on "hs_personel", it may be different.

Comment: It is same. I checked it twice.

Answer (score 0):

When binding is set to `Repeater1.DataSource = result.Entities;` you should change template code to:

```
<%#Eval("Attributes[\"hs_firstname\"]")%>
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
<%#((Entity)Container.DataItem).Attributes["hs_firstname"]%>
```

Comment: Didn't work. It returns only the record counts. What else can i try.

Comment: I've modified my answer, check it out.

Comment: But if i want to get a AliasedValue or a Referance Value how should i get?

Comment: Container.DataItem is a reference to Entity, so do it as you would do it in other code. Or create model and collect data in Page_Load